# How to understand a complicated regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I once saw a regular expression example

```
^\s*(+-)?(\d+|\d*\.\d+|\d+\.\d*)(e?(+-)?......$
```

but I just do not know how to understand/analyze this one?

Comment: I doubt that's exactly what you saw. Parentheses don't balance.

Comment: You can also use [YAPE::Regex::Explain](http://search.cpan.org/~gsullivan/YAPE-Regex-Explain-4.01/Explain.pm) for explanation of a regular expression like `use YAPE::Regex::Explain; my $exp = YAPE::Regex::Explain->new($REx)->explain;`

Comment: The two instances of `(+-)` are probably bugs as what was meant would have been `[+-]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Analyze it a bit at a time; if you see a `?`, `*`, or `+` then that modfies the previous 'group' (parenthesized group, or 'atomic' unit such as `\s` or a literal like `e`):

```
^            The start of the string
\s*          Zero or more whitespace characters.
(+-)?        An optional + or -
(
   \d+       One or more digits
 |           or
   \d*\.     Zero or more digits, followed by a .
   \d+       One or more digits
 |           or
   \d+\.     At least one digit, followed by a .
   \d*       Zero or more digits
)
(
 e?          An optional e
 (+-)?       An optional + or -
```

Here the regex trails off, and I'm not sure if the `.....` is a literal series of `.`s in the regex or just a normal ellipsis. But hopefully this is a clear explanation. (by the way, `$` means 'end of the string').

Comment: However, `(+-)?` doesn't mean "an option + or -". It means "an optional '+-' sequence." (It would have to be `(+|-)?` to mean what you said.)

Comment: Actually, it'd have to be (\+|-), since (+|-) would be a syntax error. But yeah, I was letting my guess as to what the regex was *trying* to do (I assume match a number like -1.24e+45)color my interpretation of what it actually does.

Comment: Heh. I missed the `+` being a metacharacter. (Distracted by parentheses, I guess.) That's a problem in OP's re as well.